# How to change the color of the entire row on click of button

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hello i'm new to javascript/jquery.I have this page where the user will accept or reject the request. I want to change the color of the entire row depending on the button pressed.If Accept button is pressed then the entire row should change to red & for Reject button change to green.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>MRA</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function Accept() {
        alert("You have Accepted the Request!!");
    }
    function Reject() {
        alert("You have Rejected the Request!!");
    }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1 align="center">Book</h1>
    <table align="center" width="100%">
        <tr>
            <td>
<?php
$result = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * from table  ");
echo "
    <table border='1' id='mytable' width='100%'>
        <tr>
            <th>Id</th>
            <th>User Name</th>
            <th>Purpose</th>
            <th>Attendee</th>
            <th>Date </th>
            <th>StartTime</th>
            <th>EndTime</th>
            <th>Response</th>
        </tr>";
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td align='center'><input type='text' readonly size='1' name='textid' value=". $row['id']. "></td>";
    echo "<td align='center'>" . $row['name'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td align='center'>" . $row['purpose'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td align='center'>" . $row['attendee'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td align='center'>" . $row['date'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td align='center'>" . $row['starttime'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td align='center'>" . $row['endtime'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td align='center'>" . '<input type="button" value="Accept" name="txtaccept" onclick="Accept()">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="button" value="Reject" name="txtreject" onclick="Reject()">' . "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
?>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for script part:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function Accept(el)
{
   var tr = el.parentNode.parentNode; //tr
   tr.className = "accepted";
}
function Reject(el)
{
   var tr = el.parentNode.parentNode; //tr
   tr.className = "rejected";
}
</script>
```

for css part:

```
<style type="text/css">
table { border-collapse: collapse; } //to remove cell spacings
table td { padding: 2px; }
tr.accepted, tr.accepted td { background-color: green; }
tr.rejected, tr.rejected td { background-color: red; }
</style>
```

for html part:

```
onclick="Accept(this)"
```

and

```
onclick="Reject(this)" //to pass the input elements to the functions
```

Comment: Sir i'm stuck on refresh. The color disappears

Comment: It will dissapear on refresh, you should append some code to the Accept/Reject functions to pass the state to the server using ajax. On the php rendering side you should check this state to assign class="rejected"/class="accepted" to tr elements.

Answer (score 0):

Write the following code before your body tag ends:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
       $("input[name=txtaccept]").on("click", function() {
         $( this ).parent().parent().css( "background-color", "red" );
       });
       $("input[name=txtreject]").on("click", function() {
         $( this ).parent().parent().css( "background-color", "green" );
       });
    });
    </script>
    </BODY>
```

Comment: i tried using this & it worked fine function Accept(e) {
e.parentNode.parentNode.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
}   & onClick="Accept(this)" but on refresh the color disappears.

Comment: @Ankit What I have wriiten is also correct. Maybe that is not working for you due to some other issue. For now you have found the answer  so I think problem is solved. Right?

Comment: this accept function is conflicting with something so rename it to Accept1 ,i think it should work.

Comment: Like this  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

Comment: Sir it helped but the code is changing entire table to a particular color where i want it to be only for a particular row. As i'm fetching data from db..On refresh why is the color not retained ?

Comment: First i have edited the answer try using that function in place of Accept1 function and the reason behind page refresh issue is ..the change of color is dependent on button click so when you refresh the page the button will not get clicked automatically hence it you want this trigger the click event on DOM ready.

Comment: Tell me what do you want when page is refreshed ? Do you want to retain the colors which are accepted or rejected??

Comment: Listen, you are telling me to write the whole functionality here which is not possible. Ask for help where you get stuck. For persisting the colors you need to set a parameter on database on which you can fluctuate between colors. I can guide you till here only

Comment: I have edited a little more. in place of .siblings() write.parent(), this will make the color spread on the entire row. and welcome